# How to display strings from a list using an active boolean?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to make a button where when you press it, it will show a new string. I am placing these Strings inside a List() function. My dilemma is that I am using the active boolean, where I can only put 2 strings. Is there a way to make the active boolean display the strings contained in the List, only one at a time? Here is my code thus far:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List RandomWords = ['HI', 'Bye', 'Ciao', 'Leaf'];
    List<DropdownMenuItem> dropdownItems = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < RandomWords.length; i++) {
      String currency = RandomWords[i];
    }
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: _handleTap,
      child: Container(
        width: 200,
        height: 200,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            active ? "F R U R' U' F'" : "F R U2 F' R",
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 25, color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried using a List(), but when I try to display it through the active ? bool, it just shows me all of the strings contained in the List at once. I want the active ? bool to only show one of the strings at a time, so then when I click my button, it goes on to the next string in the List. Any help is appreciated, as I really need help.

Comment: Are you trying to animate text one after another ?

Comment: A `bool` only has two values, `true` and `false`. So it can only select one of two strings. If you use an `int` you could pick any word from a list, like `RandomWords[2]` which is `'Ciao'`. You could then increment the number to get the next word.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Yes, I am.

Comment: @DavidConrad Where do I create the int? And how would I increment it afterwards? (Keep in mind that I want the text to still be 'clickable').

Comment: try using animated_text_kit